# CakePhp Routes with Controller wildcard

Tags: cakephp

I'd like reroute all  *domainname.com/affiliateXYZ* visits to an AffController reroute action.  But how?

The route element substring of 'affiliate' will be consistent and substring 'XYZ' will vary.

I would've *preferred* project requirements that had allowed **domainname.com/aff/reroute/XYX** (or **domainname.com/aff/reroute/CigarKing**) in the controller/action/parameter format, but alas.. tis not the case.

Initially I tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
Router::connect('/affiliate*',     array('controller' => 'aff', 'action' => 'reroute'));
Router::connect('/affiliate**',     array('controller' => 'aff', 'action' => 'reroute'));
Router::connect('/:controller*',     array('controller' => 'aff', 'action' => 'reroute'), array('controller'=>'(affiliate)');
```

Once in the controller reroute action I will explode the affiliateXYZ into just 'XYZ' and then proceed with things I know how to do.  My issue is routing to the controller with affiliateXYZ as the first routing element and at the same time not messing up current functionality.

I'd used `Router::connect('/:affiliate', array('controller' => 'aff', 'action' => 'reroute'),array('pass'=>array('affiliate')));` to get to the info into the controller, until I saw the negative impact on preexisting controllers (I assume because I didn't explicitly list all other controllers, which I don't think I should have to do.).

How to route w/prefix ( more accurately a substring of 'affiliate' )?

I know prefix is the wrong terminology.

Thx, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for regular expression matching, with the help of this functionality you can define how specific route elements are matched.

This option is available for the third parameter of `Router::connect()`.
You define it in `element => regex` format:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:affilate',
    array(
        'controller' => 'aff',
        'action' => 'reroute'
    ),
    array(
        'pass' => array('affilate'),
        'affilate' => 'affilate[^/]+'
    )
);
```

This would match any URL that starts with `affilate`, followd by 1 or more characters that are not a `/`.

See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements

Comment: Thx ndm.  It not only functions exactly as you describe, but it's more succinct than the verbose alternative I'd implemented based on [http://lecterror.com/articles/view/advanced-routing-with-cakephp-one-example]  Lack of regex chops was my issue. Glad to stick w/Router:connect usage as you recommend, instead of a loop over controllers and then a negative regex like at lecterror.com