# How can I set a url keyword to route to a specific controller/action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

How could I make the router to link to a specific controller/action if the url as a specific keyword inside it ?

aka I'm making a game, I want the user to be able to access it's bank by entering any url with the keyword "money" inside it. That way /showmemoney , /momoney , etc. would all link to the controller Banks.

Looking for the cakeway to do this.

Comment: This might work for you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359321/cakephp-routes-with-controller-wildcard

Comment: Did you read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration?

Comment: seriously guys, dont always send to the book as an answer. I did search there, maybe I missed something, who cares, be helpful. 

Thanks ndm,  I think this will work for me

Answer (score 0):

Read [the CakePHPs official documentation about routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration).

> Another common use for the Router is to define an “alias” for a
>   controller. Let’s say that instead of accessing our regular URL at
>   /users/some_action/5, we’d like to be able to access it by
>   /cooks/some_action/5. The following route easily takes care of that:

```
Router::connect(
    '/cooks/:action/*', array('controller' => 'users')
);
```